# Unable to resolve dependency when creating new kotlin project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Hello i wanted to start a new project with Kotlin today but it doesn't sync and error when creating the project After searching I found out that this problem was due to Gradle and fixed by changing this codes

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

But I want to use the Gradle 5.1.1, 
Is there a way to use Gradle 5.1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your android version. If your android is already updated version then open your project structure (File -> Project Structure) or type Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S then change your Android version with Gradle. 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMioC.png)